# How to pass func expression in LINQ where clause?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, where-clause, iqueryable

This is my Custom filter(Func) to pass in where clause

```
Func<Project,bool> filter = f =>
{
    bool filteredContent = true;
    if (!CreatorId.Equals(0))
        filteredContent = f.CreatedBy.Equals(CreatorId);

    if (filteredContent && !VerticalMarketId.Equals(0))
        filteredContent = f.VerticalMarketsId.Equals(VerticalMarketId);

    if (filteredContent && !ProductCategoryId.Equals(0))
        filteredContent = f.ProductCategoriesId.Equals(ProductCategoryId);

    return filteredContent;

};
```

This is my code where I get all the projects based on the conditions created in filter expression

```
 getProjects = await _context.Projects.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false && filter.Invoke(x))// Here I'm getting the exception
                .Include(PC => PC.ProjectComments.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false))
                .Include(SP => SP.SharedProjects)
                .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

> Exception:The LINQ expression (DbSet......) could not be
> translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Can someone tell how can I filter the data using expression in this?

**NOTE**: I can do ToListAsync() before applying the filter, but it'll get all the records from DB then filter on client side. But I want to filter the data on server side.

Comment: You will need an `Expression<Func<Project, bool>>` before EF can translate it

Comment: Can you please elaborate? @HansKeﬆing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out by creating a simple Expression as fololows:

```
private static Expression<Func<Project, bool>> ProjectFilterExpression(
    int creatorId, 
    int verticalMarketId, 
    int productCategoryId)
{
    Expression<Func<Project, bool>> projectFilterExpression = pfe => 
    !pfe.IsDeleted
    //CreatorId Filter
    && (creatorId.Equals(0) || pfe.CreatedBy.Equals(creatorId))
    //Vertical Market Filter
    && (verticalMarketId.Equals(0) || pfe.VerticalMarketsId.Equals(verticalMarketId))
    // Product Category Filter
    && (productCategoryId.Equals(0) || pfe.ProductCategoriesId.Equals(productCategoryId)); 
    return projectFilterExpression;
}
```

Then I call this static method inside my filter method.

```
var filter = ProjectFilterExpression(CreatorId, VerticalMarketId, ProductCategoryId);
```

And finally I applied this filter in my LINQ where clause

```
getProjects = await _context.Projects.Where(filter).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
```

It's working totally fine.

Comment: Instead of trying to build a single `Expression<>`, since your criteria is all `&&`s, I would instead conditionally call `.Where` to add each filter. eg; `query = _context.Projects.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted); if (cond) query = query.Where(f => [filter]);`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Your suggestion will work for sure. But in your suggestion it will fetch the data from DB based on 1st condition. Then it will apply other conditions on the C# object containing the data. My query was.. I want to send an expression based on which data will be filtered in DB only. So I don't have to get all the data from db then filter it in the C#. It'll take more time.

Comment: No. You should think of an `IQueryable` as a query builder. Until you enumerate the results, via `.ToList()` `.Sum(...)` etc, nothing happens.

Answer (score 4):

IF you were using `Linq To Objects` that should work but you are doing `Linq To SQL` and in this case you must think on how you would translate this function into a valid `SQL` statement. Question yourself: How could I pass this function call in a SQL Statement? Depending what you do on the body of your expression, you cannot translate it to SQL, you must be simpler sometimes.

**Candidate solution**

1. Add `PredicateBuilder` class on your project. It will give you easily logical operators to you handle expressions.

   http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx
2. Try to define an expression and pass it as argument on `Where` method of your query method chain. For sample (read the comments):

```
// define a expression with default condition
Expression<Func<Project, bool>> filter = f => !f.IsDeleted;

// check conditions to add new filtes with `And` logical operator
if (!CreatorId.Equals(0))
    filter = filter.And(f => f.CreatedBy.Equals(CreatorId));
else if (!VerticalMarketId.Equals(0))
    filter =  filter.And(f => f.VerticalMarketsId.Equals(VerticalMarketId));
else if (!ProductCategoryId.Equals(0))
    filter =  filter.And(f => f.ProductCategoriesId.Equals(ProductCategoryId));

// apply the filter on the query and execute it
getProjects = await _context.Projects.Where(filter)
    .Include(PC => PC.ProjectComments.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted))
    .Include(SP => SP.SharedProjects)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Note: I didn't test this code and it probably should be fixed somehow!

Important tips on Linq To SQL:

- Logical operators are ok and tend to be translated fine to sql;
- `Where(x => x.Children.Any(j => j.Children.Any()))`, each `Any` call generates a subquery on query scope, be careful with it given it can compromise your database performance.
- If you just need to check the existence of an item, use `queryable.Any(expression)`.
- If you need to check and then do something, prefer using `queryable.FirstOrDefault(expression)` and check if the result is null before using.
- Use paging with `.Take(int)` and `.Skip(int)`.
- Always concrete your queries by calling `.ToList()`, `.ToArray()` or async versions of these methods. Avoid passing queryable in the top layers (query can be executed out of the scope you want).

Comment: It's not working. .And method asking for one more parameter, it take two argument Left expression right expression. What is it?